# nested transaction scopes with mixed isolation levels from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, transactionscope, distributed-transactions

I have this little doubt about transaction scopes and isolation levels... so I know now that everything in a scope might or might not enlist to the root scope, (the owning one) this condition depends whether or not some conditions.

**scenario**

I have a table A which I do want to block until the whole transcope commits. I don't want any other tran to update, delete or insert so this transaction will be isolated as serializable and table B will be inserted with some key value of A but this(b) don't needs to be blocked because some users are querying the committed data or even the dirty data** so having comprehended this need I constructed this so this will be the default isolation read uncommitted.this is a light way transaction

1. If you select Required as inner TransactionScopeOption, it will join its outer transaction. That means if the outer transaction is committed then the inner transaction will commit, if the outer transaction is rolled back, then the inner transaction will be rolled back. But what if inner fails? Will outer be rolled back too?
2. The inner transactions isolation levels will be respected? one blocking and the others no.
3. How do I catch exceptions?
4. Also my procedures don't need to contain transactions right? that will just double the complexity of transaction scopes and isolation levels.

here is my code:

public bool nestedTranComplete(SomeModel thatModel)
        {

```
        int secName = 0;
        List<int> IDsList = new List<int>();
        var opts = new TransactionOptions
        {
            IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.Serializable,
            Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 9000)
        };
        var opts2 = new TransactionOptions
                {
                    IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted,
                    Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0)
                };

        try
        {
            using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, opts))
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SqlconnectionString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmdConsecutiveID = new SqlCommand("usp_GetNewSeqVal", con))
                    {
                        cmdConsecutiveID.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmdConsecutiveID.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, 
                            ParameterName = "SeqName" }).Value = "Someprocess";
                        using (SqlDataReader readr = cmdConsecutiveID.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow))
                        {
                            readr.Read();
                            secName = readr.GetInt32(0);
                        }
                        if (secName == 0)
                        {
                            throw new ArgumentException("no success on getting the new number", "SeqName");
                        }
                    }
                }
                using (TransactionScope DependingBlockingScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, opts2))
                {

                    using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(SqlconnectionString))
                    {
                        foreach (var Mynumber in thatModel.IDlists)
                        {
                            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertProces", con, tran))
                            {
                                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, 
                                    ParameterName = "one" }).Value = Mynumber;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                                    ParameterName = "two" }).Value = thatModel.someprop;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, 
                                    ParameterName = "secnumber" }).Value = secName;// here i obtain the the result of the last transaction
                                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow))
                                {
                                    if (reader.HasRows)
                                    {
                                        reader.Read();
                                        int theid = reader.GetInt32(0);
                                        IDsList.Add(theid);

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        //if (thatModel.IDlists.Count == IDsList.Count)
                        //{
                        //    return true;//or leave this alone  in order to the root transaction scope complete
                        //DependingBlockingScope.RollBack();
                        //}
                        //else
                        //{
                        //    throw new ArgumentException("no se consiguio el siguiente numero consecutivo", "SeqName");
                        //}
                    }
                    DependingBlockingScope.Complete();
                }
                scope.Complete();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is SqlException || ex is ArgumentException)
            {
                return false;
            }
            //roll back everyting and inform
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: This whole process you are describing seems to be based of the myth that nested transaction in sql server are real. They are not. When you "nest" a second transaction all that happens is @@trancount is increased by 1. When you hit a rollback or commit it does that action and reset trancount to 0 regardless of how many "nested" transactions there. And read uncommitted is far more sinister than just dirty reads. It can and will return missing and/or duplicate rows.

Comment: Here is an article about nested transactions. http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/ And here is an article about NOLOCK, using read uncommitted is the same as using NOLOCK on every single table. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: ok nested tran are like the monster under ower bed we believe they exist but when you take a look there's nothing...now the transactions are treated as a sigle piece if everything is ok then commits otherwise it rolls back. but it seems that its up to me to discover if the nested isolation levels are respected... and you are telling me to use nolock while i'm inserting data if i don't mind seeing dirty data

Comment: I am NOT telling you to use NOLOCK. In fact quite the opposite, I am suggesting that unless you fully understand that hint you should avoid it like the plague. It is not simply dirty reads, it can do lots of other nasty things when you don't understand what can happen. You can and will (randomly) get missing and/or duplicate rows. Red that article I posted about NOLOCK more closely.

Comment: OK =) i'wont  i see they are evil thank you i'll use a different isolation level to read like read commited or uncommited.thank you @Sean Lange you opened my mind.

Comment: read uncommitted is exactly the same thing as putting NOLOCK on every single table.